Windows 10, Zookeper: ERROR Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally
I'm trying to run Kafka on Windows 10.
I downloaded https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.9.0/kafka_2.13-3.9.0.tgz
I put the directory on: d:\kafka
I created two directories on d:\kafka\tmp\zookeeper\ and d:\kafka\tmp\kafka-logs\
I made these changes:
on d:\kafka\config\zookeeper.properties
# ORIGINAL dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
dataDir=d:\kafka\tmp\zookeeper

on d:\kafka\config\server.properties
# ORIGINAL log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
log.dirs=d:\kafka\tmp\kafka-logs

But when I ran: .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
I got:
d:\kafka
λ .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,822] INFO Reading configuration from: .\config\zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,829] WARN d:kafka  mpzookeeper is relative. Prepend .\ to indicate that you're sure! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,832] INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,832] INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,833] INFO observerMasterPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,833] INFO metricsProvider.className is org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.impl.DefaultMetricsProvider (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,836] INFO autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,836] INFO autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,836] INFO Purge task is not scheduled. (org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,836] WARN Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running in standalone mode (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,840] INFO Log4j 1.2 jmx support not found; jmx disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.jmx.ManagedUtil)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,842] INFO Reading configuration from: .\config\zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,843] WARN d:kafka  mpzookeeper is relative. Prepend .\ to indicate that you're sure! (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,843] INFO clientPortAddress is 0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,844] INFO secureClientPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,844] INFO observerMasterPort is not set (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,844] INFO metricsProvider.className is org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.impl.DefaultMetricsProvider (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,845] INFO Starting server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,875] INFO ServerMetrics initialized with provider org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.impl.DefaultMetricsProvider@124c278f (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerMetrics)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,886] INFO ACL digest algorithm is: SHA1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,887] INFO zookeeper.DigestAuthenticationProvider.enabled = true (org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestAuthenticationProvider)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,895] INFO zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty : false (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,898] ERROR Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog$DatadirException: Unable to create data directory d:kafka        mpzookeeper\version-2
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.<init>(FileTxnSnapLog.java:136)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:139)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:113)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:68)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:141)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:91)
Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,908] INFO ZooKeeper audit is disabled. (org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider)
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,913] ERROR Exiting JVM with code 3 (org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils)

d:\kafka

The descriptive lines are:
[2024-12-15 13:18:51,898] ERROR Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog$DatadirException: Unable to create data directory d:kafka        mpzookeeper\version-2

Do the lines need permission?
What would be my mistake?

The mistake (other than using Windows, which Kafka is not tested against), is that  you're trying to run Zookeeper when Kafka does not need it.
